# when I register with same email id, it shows expected alert and resets form. But after that it doesn't accept another entry

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a form that takes input and displays it into the table using event listener on register button. If I enter same email id for another registration, then it shows expected alert and resets form. But after that it does not allow me to submit another entry.

```
document.querySelector("#register-btn").addEventListener('click',addRows);

function addRows(){

    //get user entered data
    var fName = document.getElementById('FirstName').value;
    var lName = document.getElementById('LastName').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('exampleInputEmail1').value;
    var number = document.getElementById('mobileNumber').value;

    var table = document.getElementById("registrantList");  //access the table
    
    if(emailArr.length>0)    
      {
        for(var i=0; i<emailArr.length; i++)  //condition to check whether email is registered or not.
        {
          if(emailArr[i] == email)
          {
            alert('User Already Registered...!!!');
            document.getElementById('exampleInputEmail1').value = '';
            emailFlag = 0;
          }
          if (emailFlag == 0) 
            break;
        }
      }

    if(fName.length<3)  //condition to check whether first name is greater than 3 characters.
      alert("Enter Valid First Name...!!!");
    else if (lName.length<3) //condition to check whether last name is greater than 3 characters.
    {
      alert("Enter Valid Last Name...!!!");
    }
    else if (number.length!=10)   //condition to check mobile number is of 10 digits only
    {
      alert("Enter Valid  number..!!!");
    }
    else if (email.length<13) //condition to check email.(considered abc@gmail.com for 13 digits)
    {
      alert("Enter Valid Email...!!!");
    }
    else if (emailFlag == 1) {
      insertRowFun();
    } //if each condition is satisfied then insert row to table
     return; 
}


function insertRowFun()
{

    //get user entered data
    var fName = document.getElementById('FirstName').value;
    var lName = document.getElementById('LastName').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('exampleInputEmail1').value;
    var number = document.getElementById('mobileNumber').value;

    var table = document.getElementById("registrantList");  //access the table

    document.getElementById('noData').style.display = 'none';  //hide no data lable
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    cell1.innerHTML = fName;
    cell2.innerHTML = lName;
    cell3.innerHTML = email;
    emailArr[x] = email;  //add entered email to array.
    cell4.innerHTML = number;
    numberArr[x] = number;  //add entered mobile number to array.
    
    x++;    //increment the counter

    table.appendChild(row);
    row++;
    alert("Registered Successfully!!!");
    flag = 1;   //set flag variable
    resetForm(flag); //if data added to table then reset the form
    return;
}
```

Comment: You are implicitly declaring the variable `emailFlag` in the block that is executed if an e-mail address has already been used. Implicitly declared variables are always global so the next time you run through the `addRows()` function the variable will still equal 0 (as there is no routine resetting its value). Instead use `let emailFlag = 1` (or `var` for older browsers) at the beginning of your `addRows()` function. In case the variable is declared outside of the function, make sure it is properly reset to "1".

Comment: still I'm getting same issue. I guess there's some issue in loop. After checking for one value, it's not going back to start of the function. That's why it's not accepting another entry. Can you help me to solve it?

Comment: I would recommend to use the `debugger` command or set breakpoints. Then inspect the variables as they are in your `addRows` and `insertRowFun` functions. [Here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript) is an article about Chrome Debugging and [one for Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger). _Remark:_ you don't need the `return` statements at the end of your functions as you are not returning anything and it's already the end of the function block.